# Optimal layout of nodes given pair-wise commmunication frequencies and link speeds

Tags: algorithm, networking

Here's the problem:

You have a set of nodes in a fully connected graph. Every edge in the graph has a cost associated with it (delay). You also have a table of frequencies that tell you how often nodes in the graph communicate. How do you swap the locations of nodes to get the optimal layout (where the most frequently communicating nodes are connected by the edges with least delay)? All of the edge delays remain the same when you make a swap.

For example this graph:

[image: Graph]

with table:

```
A<->B: 20
A<->C: 30
A<->D: 40
B<->C: 10
B<->D: 10
C<->D: 30
```

Comment: With a small graph you can try all possibilities